# Retrieving a page's events using OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am currently trying to get all events from a facebook page using OpenGraph. I tried sending a request to graph.facebook.com/facebookID/events and i get an error saying i need an access token so i go to the graph explorer and manually generate one and then hard code it in using graph.facebook.com/facebookID/events?access_token= which works fine for a while but then expires.

Given that all the events and the page itself is public surely i shouldn't need access tokens?

Page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/St-Peters-Pastoral-Area/268773966498215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can understand it, to get a list of events, you need an access token, even for public events.  Just the way the API works.

Comment: how do i get an access token?

Comment: You get it from the response when the person comes to your app.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/